# How to write getIndpEnv : TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST to config.baseURL?

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have a project with several sites and I need to set the `baseURL` for each site. I would like to set them dynamically using `getIndpEnv : TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST` but I am not able to do it.

When I do : `config.baseURL = {getIndpEnv : TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST}` I become just that as string. With `config.baseURL = getIndpEnv : TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST` it just does not work.

Can this be done?

pd: Typo3 7.6

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the variable.

for this you can use `.insertData` or `.dataWrap` (probably with `.stdWrap` as it is a string property) or with a little detour a `.cObject`:

1:

```
config.baseURL = {getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST}
config.baseURL.stdWrap.insertData = 1
```

2:

```
config.baseURL.stdWrap.dataWrap = {getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST}
```

3:

```
config.baseURL.cObject = TEXT
config.baseURL.cObject.data = getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST
```